# mySQL partial participation

Tags: mysql

so I have two tables: Post and Category.
Not every post has a category, how could I write this in mySQL since the foreign key cannot be NULL?

The only thing I've tried was to do this inside the post table but obviously it didn't work

```
`INT category_id NULL,

 FOREIGN KEY(category_id)REFERENCES(category_id)`
```

I've tried to search in other questions but I didn't find anything useful to me :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Foreign keys can be `null`!

Comment: Yes I know! That's why I asked this :D

Comment: Because I don't know how to do partial participation

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys can be null. Just define the column like it.

```
category_id INT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category_table (id)
```

Comment: Cannot the foreign keys be null?

Comment: Yes, they can like this. Or what are you trying to say?